# Magento2 : Problem in block creation

Tags: magento2, custom-block

I try to modify the template of a custom option type in backend, sales order view section. In this page, product options are not displayed using a dedicated template, but only by returning Html of option Title and Value.

Based on the ikantam tutorial, I would like to use the  GetCustomizedView($optionInfo)function to create a block which will load my .phtml

the main & original .phtml displaying the options is :

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml


<?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option); ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option['value']; ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid()?>"> ...</span><span id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id = 'id' . uniqid()?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dots?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with my modified GetCustomizedView() function :

```
public function getCustomizedView($optionInfo)
{
$customizedBlock = new \Company\Module\Block\Options\Type\Customview\File();
$customizedBlock->setInfo($optionsInfo);
return $customizedBlock->toHtml();
}
```

With the new File Class : `Company\Module\Block\Options\Type\Customview\File.php`

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Options\Type\Customview;

class File extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_template = 'Company_Module::options/type/customview/xfile.phtml';

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getFileInfo()
    {
        $info = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $this->getOption()->getId());
        if (empty($info)) {
            $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        } elseif (is_array($info)) {
            $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($info);
        }
        return $info;
    }

}
```

BUT, when the constructor is called, which, in this case only calls the \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template constructor, it returns an error as the $context is not defined / passed in parameters..

Am I doing it the right way?
How to reach the $context var?

Thank you for your help,